# How to use OkHttp's HttpUrl with a request?

Tags: java, okhttp

I have an http url:

```
HttpUrl httpurl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
.scheme("https")
.host("www.google.com")
.addPathSegment("search")
.addQueryParameter("q", "polar bears")
.build();
```

How do I use that with a request? That is, how do I send a request to the url constructed by `httpurl`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Request.Builder#url(HttpUrl)`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/Request.java#L140):

```
Request r = new Request.Builder()
  .url(httpurl).build();
```

Then follow [here](http://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .method(method, requestBody)
            .url(httpurl)
            .addHeader(headerName, headerValue);
            .build();

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

    }
});
```